# Magento 2.4 - Stock Alerts not showing

Tags: stock, out-of-stock, stock-alert

I can't figure out why, buy products alerts aren't showing.

here's my config;

[image]

[image]

[image]

Would anyone have any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: 1.is your email communication working properly for other store emails? 2.do you have any errors logged?

Answer (score 0):

If by 'not showing' you mean that the option to subscribe to the alerts is not displayed on frontend, please check this https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/inventory-product-alerts.html:

> The *Notify me when this product is in stock* message appears only when Display Out of Stock Products is set to Yes (located in the Configuration at Catalog > Inventory > Stock Options).

Comment: I do mean that yes, but out of stock products are showing. It just displays the product out of stock but with no options to subscribe for when the product comes back into stock. I've edited the first post and added further screenshots.

Comment: check for errors logged at server level and the corectness of the mail server configurations.

Comment: Mail Server config is fine, which log would you suggest I look in? I can't find anything. Perhaps I've overlooked something

Comment: check logs inside <project_root>/var/log, maybe you can find something relevant. also, maybe the theme you are using has no support for the product alerts, check this track as well

Comment: I've gone through all the logs, nothing there. So it must be that my theme doesn't support product alerts? I'll have a dig into this and see what I can do. I'll keep you posted!

Comment: i would think something about the theme could interfere with this, but it's only you who can tell as you have the code.